# How to capture traffic of Desktop Application Using Fiddler

Tags: desktop-application, fiddler

Hi Am unnable to capture traffic of Desktop Application using fiddler. Please do tell the configuration settings of fiddler for desktop Application.

Comment: What's the *exact* application you're asking about, and are you sure it's using HTTP?

Answer (score -1):

When you start the fiddler , it will automatically set proxy in browser with
**ip -->127.0.0.1 and port :8888**

check your browser settings whether proxy setting to above ip and port
in case if the settings are ok , then check is there any settings in application to set proxy like in GTalk connections 
if you found any then set proxy settings with
**ip -->127.0.0.1 and port :8888**
hope this will helpful